# Facebook Login api has a missing UserName

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Since v 2.* of Facebook's login/oauth api, the `UserName` field has been dropped. Sad but fine (and yes, the reason was because of facebook email spam).

I've read about how some people are using the userId plus some other route to determine the username.

I thought it was `https://www.facebook.com/<userId>` which then does a redirect to `https://www.facebook.com/<userName>`. When I try this, I get a 404 :/

Also, when I retrieve my own user data from `v2.4/me` endpoint, I have a property in the json payload that is:

`"link": "http://www.facebook.com/<myuserid>"`

Trying that link also 404's. (Notice the `http` is not secure. going there does a **307** redirect to https ... but then I get the 404).

Can anyone tell me the route/endpoint I need to use, please? Or what i've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to use the username for anything anymore, it is only possible to get it by scraping the profile page of the user, which is not allowed: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Some platforms are doing that, and you should report them to Facebook.

If you want to identify the user, just use the App Scoped ID you get after authorizing him.

Comment: The `App Scoped ID` ? Is that the Id which is a long number?

Comment: yes, it is the id you get after authorizing a user and calling the /me endpoint